# How to add Twitch API embed channel link

Tags: javascript, html, twitch

How do I add Twitch Api streaming video embed link to this code?

```
var result=" <div class='row' id='"+status+"'> <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-4'> <span class='logo'><img class='img img-circle' src='"+logo+"'></span> <a href='"+channel_link+"'> <span class='name text-center'>"+name+"</span> </a> </div> <div class='col-md-9 col-xs-8 text-center' id='statusdescription'> <span class='game'>"+game+"</span> <span class='status'>"+statusdesc+"</span> </div> </div>";
```

It is for clicking on the logo image to see the Twitch live stream video in iframe on my website.

Embed Channel:

```
<iframe src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=ogamingsc2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" height="378" width="620"></iframe><a href="https://www.twitch.tv/ogamingsc2?tt_content=text_link&tt_medium=live_embed" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px; text-decoration:underline;">Watch live video from OgamingSC2 on www.twitch.tv</a>
```

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! please show us what you have tried so far and where you are stuck so we can better help you.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Now, re-edit your question properly.

Comment: @Scaramouche - Yes, I have tried to add code:  <a  src= "https://player.twitch.tv/?channel="+channel_link+"'>           
Unfortunately, it shows error. It says unexpected identifier.                     
                                                                                                              
var result=" <div class='row' id='"+status+"'> <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-4'> <span class='logo'> <a  src= "https://player.twitch.tv/?channel="+channel_link+"'> <img class='img img-circle' src='"+logo+"'></span>